# how to use "LIKE" in Linq to Object

Tags: linq-to-objects

I am using Linq to Object, now how can i use some thing like "LIKE" used in sql query to filter data?

Answer (score 3):

Use a combination of `Contains`, `StartsWith`, and `EndsWith`. These are all methods or extension methods on `System.String` and will work with LINQ. If this doesn't solve your problem, you will be forced to use regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
    string searchString = "NAME";
    List<string> lstNames = new List<string>()
                {"Name1"
                ,"Name2"
                ,"Name3"
                ,"Other names"
                ,"Something else"};
```

The below query(s) will accomplish the work

```
        var query1 = (from name in lstNames
                      where name.ToUpper().Contains(searchString)
                      select name);

        var query2 = lstNames.FindAll(name => name.ToUpper().Contains(searchString));

        var query3 = lstNames.Where(name => name.ToUpper().Contains(searchString));
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Use a Regex and call the IsMatch method. The *%* wildcard maps to *.** and the ___ wildcard maps to *.*.

Comment: No, never. BAD thing... the moment the same query should run against a database and you do a full table load to the client. Ouch.

Comment: The question was about LINQ to Objects, not LINQ to SQL or other database. Some database LINQ providers don't support the Contains, StartsWith, or EndsWith methods, either.

Answer (score 0):

Seconded. Contains, StartsWith and EndsWith are the equivalents. There is no "LIKE 'a%b'", but this IS a rare case.